# Multiple AJAX request in a loop with synchronized message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

AJAX requests are needed to  add 10 customers through a loop using jQuery.

When 1st customer is added, it should display “1 of 10 added”.
When 2nd customer is added, it should display “2 of 10 added”. 
and so on.

But, the following functions displays only last message “10 of 10 added” and browser keeps busy while these 10 customers are added.

```
function addCustomer(total) 
{
    var addedIndex = parseInt($("#added-index").val());

    $.ajaxSetup({cache : false});
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_customer.php",
        data: "added_no=" + document.getElementById("added-index").value,
        global: false,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#added-index").val(addedIndex + 1);
            addedIndex = parseInt($("#added-index").val());

            if (addedIndex < total) {
                addCustomer(total);
            }
            else {
                $("#cc-msg").html(html);
            }           
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Read about closures. I think this is the most essential part of JS, and most of the problems are because of developers are not understanding it completely.

Comment: If you don't want the browser to be locked up, remove `async: false`. The whole point of AJAX is that it's supposed to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to  *Anthony Grist* comments, this AJAX request should not have `async: false` parameter. So, the answer is:

```
function addCustomer(total) 
{
    var addedIndex = parseInt($("#added-index").val());

    $.ajaxSetup({cache : false});
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_cc.php",
        data: "added_no=" + document.getElementById("added-index").value,
        global: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#added-index").val(addedIndex + 1);
            addedIndex = parseInt($("#added-index").val());

            if (addedIndex < total) {
                addCustomer(total);
            }
            else {
                $("#cc-msg").html(html);
            }    
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the .append()

```
$("#cc-msg").append(html + '<img src="img/ajax_loader.gif" width="35" hspace="150" height="35" vspace="7" align="middle" >');
```

Comment: It has been solved after removing async: false according to Anthony Grist's comments.

Comment: Try to offer details about your answer, not just a solution. The poster needs to understand what he's doing.